# Why is lisp saying this parameter is not a list?

Tags: common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

I am working through the MP3 database example in Peter Seibel's *Practical Common Lisp*. Seibel demonstrates how macros can be used to shorten the code for the `where` function; so now, I am trying to use a macro to shorten the code for the `update` function. (The original version of the `update` function is included for reference.) When I run my code, the following error originates from the second-to-last line --

```
*** - CAR: TERMS is not a list
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
(defvar *db* nil)
(defun add-record (cd) 
  (push cd *db*))

(defun dump-db ()
  (dolist (cd *db*)
    (format t "~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%" cd)))

(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))

(defun prompt-for-cd ()
  (make-cd
    (prompt-read "Title")
    (prompt-read "Artist")
    (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Rating") :junk-allowed t) 0)
    (y-or-n-p "Ripped [y/n]: ")))

(defun add-cds ()
  (loop (add-record (prompt-for-cd) )
        (if (not (y-or-n-p "Another? [y/n]: ")) (return) )))

(defun save-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (out filename
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :supersede)
                  (with-standard-io-syntax
                    (print *db* out))))

(defun load-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (in filename)
                  (with-standard-io-syntax
                    (setf *db* (read in) ))))

(defun select (selector-fn)
  (remove-if-not selector-fn *db*))

(defun make-comparison-expr (field value)
  `(equal (getf cd ,field) ,value))

(defun make-comparison-list (func fields)
  (loop while fields
        collecting (funcall func (pop fields) (pop fields))))

(defmacro where (&rest clauses)
  `#'(lambda (cd) (and ,@(make-comparison-list 'make-comparison-expr clauses))))

(defun make-update-expr (field value)
  `(setf (getf row ,field) ,value))

(defmacro make-update-list (fields)
  (make-comparison-list 'make-update-expr fields))

(defun update (selector-fn &rest terms)
  (print (type-of terms))
  (setf *db*
        (mapcar
          #'(lambda (row)
             (when (funcall selector-fn row)
               (make-update-list terms))
             row)
          *db*)))

;(defun update (selector-fn &key title artist rating (ripped nil ripped-p))
;  (setf *db*
;        (mapcar
;          #'(lambda (row)
;             (when (funcall selector-fn row)
;               (if title    (setf (getf row :title) title) )
;               (if artist   (setf (getf row :artist) artist) )
;               (if rating   (setf (getf row :rating) rating) )
;               (if ripped-p (setf (getf row :ripped) ripped) ))
;             row)
;          *db*)))

(defun delete-rows (selector-fn)
  (setf *db* (remove-if selector-fn *db*)))

;(loop (print (eval (read))))
(add-record (make-cd "Be" "Common" 9 nil))
(add-record (make-cd "Like Water for Chocolate" "Common" 9 nil))
(add-record (make-cd "Be" "Beatles" 9 nil))

(dump-db)
(update (where :artist "Common" :title "Be") :rating 8)
(dump-db)
```

-----Edit-----

I figured it out. The solution was to make `update` a macro and to make `make-update-list` a function. This way, `make-update-list` could evaluate fields at run-time and `update` can still abstract away some tedious if statements. Here is the updated `update` and `make-update-list` below:

```
(defun make-update-list (fields)
  (make-comparison-list 'make-update-expr fields))

(defmacro update (selector-fn &rest terms)
  `(setf *db*
        (mapcar
          #'(lambda (row)
             (when (funcall ,selector-fn row)
               ,@(make-update-list terms))
             row)
          *db*)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macroexpansion of that `make-update-list` is done in a separate phase (called "macroexpansion phase") - which occurs around the time a piece of code is compiled or loaded; in this case we're talking about compilation / loading of `update`. The macro gets expanded with `fields` bound to the *symbol* `terms`, which (the symbol itself) is used as a value in `make-comparison-list`; I suppose that was not what you expected.

Note, if you go and compile the file line-by-line (`C-c C-c` in Emacs + SLIME), it'll tell you right during *compilation* of `update` that the macro expansion fails because "the value TERMS is not of type LIST".

Generally, think of macros as functions that take in their arguments *unevaluated* - i.e. a form `(make-update-list foo)` will get expanded with the macro parameter's `fields` value bound to `foo`. What you're trying to achieve here - code generation based on run-time values - is a bit more difficult to do.

Comment: I was hoping you could expand on that last sentence a bit. Is it impossible, or just harder to do? I would think it would be impossible, since there is usually a hard demarcation between compile-time and run-time for programming languages. Or is there a way?

Comment: It's a bit more cumbersome. You want to use `eval`  to evaluate s-expressions you built at runtime. `eval` performs macroexpansion phase too (as if by `macroexpand-1`). See more at http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eval.htm. I purposefully didn't expand on that last part of my comments, because there _may_ be some caveats wrt. macros at runtime that I'm not experienced enough to properly explain.

That said, doing the thing you're doing at runtime doesn't make sense - the overhead of code generation will be greater than that of skipping simple `if`s.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to take the `car` of a symbol!

```
> (car 'terms)
*** - CAR: TERMS is not a list
```

Think of macros as a function that, when used, replaces the *code* with the result of the macro function everywhere it's used. At this time variables are just symbols and have no meaning besides that.

When you do `(make-update-list terms)` it will call the macro function with the argument `fields` being the symbol you passed, which is `terms`. Since it's a symbol it cannot be iterated like you are trying. You may iterate it at runtime when it surely is a list, but as a macro it isn't a list until you are passing it a list like `(make-update-list (title artist rating ripped))`.

If it is dynamic in runtime then your macro needs to expand to code that does most of its magic at runtime. Thus a macro is just a source rewriting service and should not have anything to do with what variable might be at runtime since then it has already done its thing.